# NodeJs / Express how to load validation midleware

Tags: node.js, express

My main file is called index.js where i load some of the stuff and then i branch to my routes which are in different files. My question now is as i have several app.use parts like this one who checks for a valid token.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
// check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
// decode token
if (token) {
    console.log('MyToken:'+token)

  // verifies secret and checks exp
  jwt.verify(token, 'MySuperSecret', function(err, decoded) {      
    if (err) {
        if (err.name === 'TokenExpiredError')
        {
            return res.status(401).send({ success: false, error: err.name, message: err.message, expiredAt: err.expiredAt })   
        }
        else{
            return res.send({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
        }


    } else {
      // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
      console.log('success')
      req.decoded = decoded;   
      res.locals.decoded = decoded;
      next();
    }
  });

} else {

  // if there is no token
  // return an error
  return res.status(403).send({ 
      success: false, 
      message: 'No token provided.' 
  });

}
```

})

my question is if i place this app.use function in my index.js before i declare any of the separate routes like

```
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
```

will code still hit and use the app.use function or do i have to place the app.use function on top of every route file to protect the routes underneath.
Trying to figure out what the best approach is if one has more then 1 route file.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply middleware by specifying a regular expression. Perhaps `app.use('/api.*', myMiddleware)` will help.

Otherwise you could just try the thing out and see if it works.